# Оптимальный размер программы на Android

Tags: java, android

В процессе разработки приложения намерен воспользоваться *SQLite* хранением данных.

Существуют ли ограничения на размер приложения, закачиваемого пользователем, и если есть, каким он (размер приложения) должен быть оптимальным?

Comment: Чем меньше, тем лучше, конечно, но никто не запрещает грузить огромные приложения.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Размер apk ограничен [50 мб](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/03/android-apps-break-50mb-barrier.html). Плюс можно делать специальные файлы дополнение и докачивать до 4 гигабайт данных.

Оптимальный размер  - это минимальный размер. Если Ваше приложение показывает две картинки и размер его 50 мб - пользователи будут крутить носом.